# E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling class with @Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

so i got Retrofit API + Gson as converter and i have parcelable class to pass to various activities...

```
@Parcelize
data class GenericList<T>(
    @SerializedName("data") var data: @RawValue List<T>
) : Parcelable
```

Here is a generic list class which is parcelable with following:

```
abstract class AbsPlot : Parcelable {

    abstract var rating: Map<String, Rating>?
    abstract var plots: GenericList<Plot>?
    ....
    abstract var languages: GenericList<Language>?

}

@Parcelize
data class Plot(
        @SerializedName("rating") override var rating: Map<String, Rating>?,
        @SerializedName("plots") override var plots: GenericList<Plot>?,
        ....
        @SerializedName("languages") override var languages: GenericList<Language>?,
) : AbsPlot()
```

Once i want to un-parcel those class, it crashes with 
***Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling***

What can be a solution?

Comment: With Serializable interface it does work, however i can't call it a fix, because it's a lot slower then Parcelable...

Comment: Could you post the code that throws the exception?  Probably where you're trying to read this out of the Bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be the `@RawValue` annotation.

From its javadoc:

> Write the corresponding property value with [android.os.Parcel.writeValue].
>    Serialization may fail at runtime, depending on actual property value type.

It may be having some trouble serializing the generic type T. That's all I can guess without more details on which class couldn't be found.

I would suggest that you avoid using that annotation and use the compiler generics options like so:

```
@Parcelize
data class GenericList<T : Parcelable>(
    @SerializedName("…") val data: List<T>
) : Parcelable
```

I may also suggest, if it could be possible, making `AbsPlot` an interface and mark as `Parcelable` each of the implementations of the interface.

Another thing that makes me doubt is to check whether the class `Ratings` is `Parcelable`.

Comment: T : Parcelable <- this helped, thanks, will add bounty when available

Comment: I'm glad it helped!!